# URI-Formatter not supported in Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, uri

I'm working on a legacy project, and through debugging and re-engineering i stumbled upon the following error.

The documents are send to the location `http://localhost:8080/Files`

In the existing application it is handled like this

```
1 var path = Export.Path; <- in Debug it is `http://localhost:8080/Files`
2 Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
```

At Line 2 the following Exception is thrown:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=URI-Formate not supported.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       in System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
       in System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
       in System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
       in System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(String path)
       in Controller.cs:Line 125.
       in lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       in System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       in System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       in System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
       in System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

The directory exists and I can access it via the url-line in the browser. I searched through multiple solutions but found nothing that fits my problem.

Comment: Directory = file location in the file system. HTTP = remote resource accessed over HTTP protocol. What you're presumably getting through the URL you've mentioned is a HTML directory listing generated by whatever web server you're using.

Comment: Why is the application even changing the current directory from a controller action? That's global state for the entire process...

Comment: Thanks John, that was helpful! @yaakov I don't know - as I've written it is a legacy project and I'm trying to get familiar with it.